# How to disable host-manager.logs in tomcat9?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat9

I upgraded to `tomcat9`, and suddenly I have `manager.yyyy-mm-dd.log` and `host-manager.yyyy-mm-dd.log` files.

How can I disable them?

I already tried setting `/etc/tomcat9/conf/logging.properties`:

```
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = OFF
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = OFF
```

Still the files are generated (without content).
How can I even prevent the creation of these files?

Answer (score 2):

In the *"Handler specific properties"* section of **conf/logging.properties** simply comment out, or delete, these eight lines for **manager** and **host-manager**:

```
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = manager.
3manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.maxDays = 90
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.level = FINE
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.prefix = host-manager.
4host-manager.org.apache.juli.AsyncFileHandler.maxDays = 90
```

After that the **manager.{yyyy-mm-dd}.log** and **host-manager.{yyyy-mm-dd}.log** files will not be created whenever you start Tomcat.

I tested this using Tomcat 9.0.7.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I just took the manager appender definitions out of the `handler=` property.